# Spring Security 3.0 functionality to Spring security 2.0.2

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, login-control

Can anybody tell me what is replacement of

```
<bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
```

in Spring Security 2.0.2.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The same class in the same package is still there. If you use the namespace configuration, you don't have to declare this bean manually, because the `<security:form-login>` element will wire it up by default.

Comment: i do not have <security:form-login> element.  can you please provide the example to doing that in SS 2.0.2

Comment: Oh sorry, I've misunderstood your question. I thought you were upgrading to 3.x. I'm not sure the same thing is available in 2.0.2. But that's an almost 5 years old version... can't you upgrade?